# How is prestressing with losses self-balanced?

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-engineering, concrete, prestressed-concrete

By definition, prestressing is a self-balanced load. This is because it is in fact merely an applied state of internal stresses.

This can also be demonstrated mathematically (in this case for a simple parabolic cable) via Lin's load-balancing method.

For a cable which follows the layout given by
$$ y(x) = \dfrac{4e}{L^2}x^2 $$
where $e$ is the vertical distance between the maximum and minimum points of the parabola, $L$ is the span of the cable, and $x=y=0$ is located at the minimum point of the layout, the equivalent load is 
$$ q = \dfrac{8Pe}{L^2}$$
where $P$ is the prestress force.

Therefore, the total vertical load given by the distributed load is $\dfrac{8Pe}{L}$.

This force is countered by the vertical forces applied at the anchors. These are equal to $P\sin(\theta) \approx P\theta$ and $y'(x) \approx \theta$, so the forces are each equal to $Py'\left(\frac{L}{2}\right) = \dfrac{4Pe}{L}$ and combined are equal (and opposite) to the total distributed load. So the total global load applied is null.

Now, what if we consider friction losses between the cable and the duct in a post-tensioned beam? Then the combined forces at the extremities remain equal to $\dfrac{8Pe}{L}$, but the total distributed load will be reduced by the losses, implying in a non-balanced load, which is impossible.

This may be adjusted by the anchorage slip losses, but what if we assume a hypothetical anchor which doesn't slip? Is this impossible and slippage is necessary to make the load balanced?

And how are the remaining losses (elastic deformation, creep, shrinkage and relaxation) affected?

Comment: By friction losses, what exactly do you mean?  Bond between the prestressing strands and the concrete/grout?

Comment: Ah, this is for post-tensioned cables, not pre-tensioned. It is the friction between the cable and the duct at the moment of jacking. @grfrazee

Comment: Ok, I see.  Your title is a little misleading, then :-)

Comment: Well, post-tensioning is still considered prestress ("prestressing with post-tensioned cables"). @grfrazee

Comment: @grfrazee, also, the question isn't specific for friction losses. If you have anchorage slippage in a pre-tensioned cable, then the inverse question applies: you have a reduced concentrated load at the extremities and a not-so-reduced distributed load, which means you'll end with a greater total distributed load than concentrated loads, as I understand it. This applies to any loss that causes a non-uniform reduction in stress along the cable.

Comment: Understood.  I'll admit that my experience with pre/post-tensioning isn't all that great.  It's weird for me to call post-tensioned structures "prestressed" since you're applying the tensioning after construction, but I suppose "prestressing" really just means that the stress is applied before the load occurs.  Ah, the wonderful vagaries of the English language...

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "self-balanced"? My understanding of T.Y. Lin's load balancing method, is that the prestressing is only "balancing" external loads.

Comment: @CableStay, to prestress is simply to apply an internal stress state. This means that the global external force applied by the prestress' equivalent loads is null. If you sum the concentrated forces at the extremities with the distributed forces along the span, the result must be equal to zero. To visualize it simply, think of a fictional beam with no self-weight just floating in the air. You then prestress it. If the prestress' equivalent external forces did not cancel each other out, then the beam would start flying off into the sunset due to the unbalanced force.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand you. I'm not familiar with Lin's load balancing method but does it account for friction? The cable layout seems way to simple for that. If not the assumption that your cable layout will result in a perfect evenly distributed equivalent load will not hold once you take friction into account. If this causes a problem you might be able to minimize it by tensioning and detensioning in a series of steps to spread the friction out more evenly through the duct, but it will never be perfectly even.

Comment: To express it clearer; the total equivalent load will not change with friction, but it's distribution will.

Comment: @Mr.P, no, Lin's method does not take normally take friction losses into account, but that can be trivially done by changing $P$ in the equation to $P(x)$, where the value of $P$ changes along the span due to friction (and other) losses. This, however, implies in a loss of total equivalent load.

Comment: @Mr.P, I've just done some tests on an example case and noticed you're right. Now I need to figure out how to quantify this redistribution. Let me think whether to edit this question (which would be a pretty substantial rewrite) or answer it showing the need for this redistribution (or let you answer it) and then ask another question for help in how to define it.

Comment: I can't provide a very clear answer to that, you could perhaps estimate it by treating the frictional losses as several separate loads (in the friction zones directed tangentially to your cable) on your specimen that you superposition on top of the evenly distributed load (based on the lowest stress you have in the cable). If you have a FE-model of the specimen with friction losses accounted for perhaps you could get some feel for it if you look at the curvature of the member. But I'm not quite sure this has any practical concern? Are you trying to achieve anything in particular?

Comment: @mr.p, it's not of immediate concern, but it's certainly practical. Equivalent loading is a method which allows for easy calculation of prestressing loading, but if it can't take losses into consideration in a reasonable manner (such as satisfying the fundamental condition of being self-balanced), then it cannot be used in a real project.

Comment: Well, I think it can be a good simplified design method. It gives you a nice parabolic profile for a given load to start from. But yes, you better provide a more detailed analysis in the end. In the projects where I have used it so far sizes have been mainly governed by strength, which is largely unaffected by pre-stressing, and then we've tensioned them to meet deflection criteria. There's never been any real need to be extraordinarily clever about it yet (sadly). Here the contractor usually have engineers with expertise in their preferred methods that we involve in the final calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments by @Mr.P nudged me to realize that there is a redistribution of equivalent loads due to losses which cannot be trivially encompassed by Lin's method.

To demonstrate this, take the following simply-supported beam (ignore all concepts of units or scale here, this is a thought exercise).

[image]

The bending moment diagram solely due to prestress for this beam will be the following polygonal diagram (before any losses, assuming $P\cos\theta \approx P$):

[image]

This is equivalent to the diagram obtained by a concentrated vertical load at midspan equal to $F = 2P\sin\theta \approx 40$, which is balanced out by the two vertical loads at the supports, each equal to $P\sin\theta \approx 20$ (in the opposite direction).

However, let us now consider friction losses. Let's assume they cause a 10% reduction to the stress in the tendon at midspan. This implies that the bending moment at midspan will also be reduced by 10%, and will therefore equal 90. However, the diagram's profile is no longer polygonal.

That can be easily observed by looking at the bending moment at any other point. In an isostatic structure, the bending moment is simply equal to $P \cdot e$, where $e$ is the distance between the cable and the centroid. Looking at quarter-span, the bending moment before losses was equal to $100\cdot0.5=50$, or exactly half of the mid-span moment. To calculate after losses, however, we need to calculate the force at this point. Simplifying things considerably, let's assume the loss here is half of that at midspan, so only 5%.<sup>1</sup> In that case, the bending moment at quarter-span will be equal to $95\cdot0.5=47.5$, which is ***not*** equal to half of the mid-span moment of 90.

Indeed, the bending moment diagram from support to midspan becomes of the form

$$M = Pe\left(\dfrac{2x}{L}-0.1\left(\dfrac{2x}{L}\right)^2\right)$$

where $e$ is the distance of the cable to the centroid at midspan, $L$ is the span, and $0.1$ represents the 10% loss of prestress at midspan.

[image]

Getting the first and second derivatives of this equation gives us the equivalent concentrated load at midspan and the uniform load distributed along the entire span, respectively:

$$\begin{align}
M' = Q &= Pe\left(\dfrac{2}{L} - 0.2\dfrac{4x}{L^2}\right) \\
Q\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right) &= \dfrac{1.6Pe}{L} \therefore F = 2Q\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right) = 32 \\
M'' = q &= \dfrac{0.8Pe}{L^2} = 0.8
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the equivalent loading which generates the correct (simplified) bending moment diagram after friction losses is the following:

[image]

This implies in a new uniform load which did not appear before losses, a representation of the load redistribution described by @Mr.P. The equivalent concentrated load at midspan is also no longer equal to $F = 2P\sin\theta$, which would have resulted in $F \approx 36$. The prestress, however, is balanced, since $32 + 0.8\cdot10 = 40$, as expected.

---

The same reasoning can be applied to parabolic cables. For the following beam:

[image]

the uniform equivalent load is $q = \dfrac{8Pe}{L^2} = 2$, which generates a total upwards force of $2\cdot32=64$, to be cancelled out by the concentrated downwards forces of 32 at each support. The bending moment diagram before any losses is:

[image]

However, assuming once again a 10% loss due to friction at midspan, and that the friction-loss profile is linear, the bending moment diagram becomes:

[image]

which has the following cubic equation (with $x=0$ at the midspan):

$$M = 2.00\cdot128\left(1-\left(\dfrac{2x}{L}\right)^2\right)\left(0.9+0.1\dfrac{2x}{L}\right)$$

getting the first and second derivatives, I can find the equivalent loading, which in this case is equal to:

[image]

Given what we saw with the first example, it comes as no surprise that there's an increase in the distributed load near the supports. It also makes intuitive sense that the distributed load is reduced near the midspan. How that concentrated load at midspan comes to be, however, I have no idea. However, once again the prestress is self-balanced: $\dfrac{1.8+2.4}{2}\cdot32-3.2=64$.

This answer therefore answers the question posed of how prestressing with losses is self-balanced: the equivalent load is redistributed, but the total value is not modified. That being said, I cannot explain how to calculate this redistribution in a general case because, well, I don't know how that's done.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Though friction losses are usually quite linear (or polygonal), this is a poor assumption. After all, the 10% loss at midspan must include the effect of the concentrated angle change at that point. At quarter-span, the losses are only due to linear friction loss, and will therefore probably be substantially lower than 5%. That being said, we can just state that 10% is at the point immediately before the angle change, where the bending moment approaches 100 but where only linear friction losses have occurred.</sub>

<sub>All diagrams obtained with [Ftool](https://www.ftool.com.br/Ftool/), a free 2D frame analysis tool.</sub>

Comment: Nice write-up!

*In theory* you could produce a tendon profile that gives you a perfectly even equivalent load. It was way too long ago since I took my heavy calculus classes to even begin figuring out how to do it though. It would also look quite daunting once you take slip, staggered tensioning, etc. into account. Luckily for me, since the reality of our business is quite brutish, there's usually diminishing returns trying to find the perfect solution rather than settling for something close enough :)